# Is this a demonstration that the shellshock patch isn't working?

Tags: shellshock, bash

I am checking my systems with the following command:

```
env X="() { :;} ; echo busted" /bin/sh -c "echo completed"
```

Which gives me: "completed", with no "busted", which seems good.
So I tried again with:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

Which results in:

```
bash: warning: testbug: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `testbug'
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
this is a test
```

Which again, seems good.  However, when I run:

```
env x='()' ; echo vulnerable; bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

I get a dump of all environmental vars, followed by:

```
_=/usr/bin/env
x=()
vulnerable
bash: warning: testbug: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `testbug'
this is a test
```

Now I am concerned.  Should I be?

EDIT:  The two references to 'testbug' are due to a prior test which defined that variable.  I unset that variable and the rest of the output still shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having bash execute the commands separated by ';' in turn.  This is normal behavior and not an indicator that the bug's patch is inadequate.

Comment: Fair enough, but why is it dumping everything as if I ran `printenv`?

Comment: DESCRIPTION
env executes utility after modifying the environment as specified on the command line.  The option name=value specifies an environmental variable, name, with a value of value. --- So, env is doing what is expected in this case.